# SQL - remove duplicate tuples, even if values are out of order

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
name_1 name_2 value
-------------------
john   alex    6
alex   john    6
bob    rick    7
rick   bob     7
```

I want to get rid of the duplicates so I'm left with this:

```
name_1 name_2 value
-------------------
john   alex    6
rick   bob     7
```

Does `distinct` work? And if so, how would I apply it?

**EDIT:**

I'm not concerned about the order of the names in the final table. I am looking for **name pairs**. So I am treating `john alex` the same as `alex john`. Therefore, I want to get rid of those "duplicates"

Comment: `distinct` won't work, name_1 john and name_2 alex is considered different from name_1 alex and name_2 john

Comment: are the duplicates always out of order in terms of name? or could they be in the same order?

Comment: The duplicates will always be out of order.

Comment: Any reason it's `john alex` vs `alex john`?  Without knowing the logic, shouldn't it also be `bob rick`?  To answer your question, you can't use `distinct` for this.  Perhaps `least` and `greatest` could help with `distinct`...

Comment: I'm not concerned about the order of the names in the final table. I am looking for **name pairs**. So I am treating `john alex` the same as `alex john`. Therefore, I want to get rid of those "duplicates"

Comment: What is the expected behaviour if you have a row `'alex', 'john', 6` and another row `'john', 'alex', 5` (same names, different value) as you only mention duplicates based on the name pairs?

Comment: @MT0 Good question. In this particular situation I have, the algorithm/logic is such that the pairs will **always** produce the same value. There will never be two tuples with the same names (in different orders) and two different values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one option using `least` with `greatest` and `distinct`:

```
select distinct least(name_1, name_2) name_1,
       greatest(name_1, name_2) name_2,
       value
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5cddf/2)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Never knew about the `least` and `greatest` functions.

Comment: What if the names are of equal value? What then?

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d0f5/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table table_name (name1, name2, value) AS
SELECT 'john', 'alex', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'alex', 'john', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bob',  'rick', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'rick', 'bob',  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'alice','carol',7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'carol','alice',7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'david','david',5 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT name1,
       name2,
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER()
           OVER ( PARTITION BY LEAST( NAME1, NAME2 ),
                               GREATEST( NAME1, NAME2 ),
                               VALUE
                  ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS RN
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  RN = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d0f5/1/0)**:

```
| NAME1 | NAME2 | VALUE |
|-------|-------|-------|
|  john |  alex |     6 |
| alice | carol |     7 |
|   bob |  rick |     7 |
| david | david |     5 |
```

**Deleting Duplicates**:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT rid
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROWID AS rid,
           ROW_NUMBER()
             OVER ( PARTITION BY LEAST( name1, name2 ),
                                 GREATEST( name1, name2 ),
                                 VALUE
                    ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
    FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE rn > 1
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73c2b/1/0)**:

```
| NAME1 | NAME2 | VALUE |
|-------|-------|-------|
|  john |  alex |     6 |
|   bob |  rick |     7 |
| alice | carol |     7 |
| david | david |     5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `WITH` clause and `ROW_NUMBER()` function

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY value ORDER BY Value) rank_n
            ,name_1
            ,name_2
            ,value
    FROM yourtable)
SELECT name_1, name_2, Value
FROM C
WHERE rank_n = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6adce/3)

Comment: This will not work if there are two sets of names both with the same value.

Comment: You are partitioning by `value` and ordering by `value` so every row in each partition will be considered equivalent and every row will have `rank_n=1`. The result is that you will return every row and not filter the query at all. [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6adce/2)

Comment: You are right @MT0. Updated and thank for the sqlfiddle

Comment: Your updated query discards the `'alice', 'carol', 7` row when this is not a duplicate of any of the rows you retain. As I said in my first comment "This will not work if there are two sets of names both with the same value."

Comment: SO wants to remove duplicates based on `value` not the `name_1` and `name_2`

Comment: The OP stated "treating `john alex` the same as `alex john`" which does not mean "treating `john alex` the same as `alice carol`". They are comparing pairs of values rather than the `value` column.